# SynchronizationContext lost after Task.Yield()

Tags: c#, async-await, synchronizationcontext

I've been having issues passing around a Culture between threads. I've managed to get it somewhat working using a Synchronization context, but in one part of my code I use a Task.Yield(). After this piece of code, my context is lost meaning all subsequent awaits/yields after this point do not use my custom SynchronizationContext.

I've boiled it down to a very simple test and I can see that after our Task.Yield, Our SynchronizationContext is lost.

Synchronization Context Class :

```
public class TestSynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext
{
}
```

Unit Test :

```
[Test]
public async Task TestHere()
{
    TestSynchronizationContext context = new TestSynchronizationContext();
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(context);
    var something1 = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    await Task.Yield();
    var something = SynchronizationContext.Current;
}
```

EDIT : If I use a new Task, the context is preserved if I can pass in the correct TaskScheduler (Although... It's the scheduler, not the Synchronization context). Such as the following :

```
[Test]
public async Task TestHere()
{
    TestSynchronizationContext context = new TestSynchronizationContext();
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(context);
    CultureInfo taskCulture = null;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () => { taskContext = SynchronizationContext.Current; },
            CancellationToken.None,
            TaskCreationOptions.None,
            TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
            ).Wait();
    Assert.AreEqual(context.GetType(), taskContext.GetType());
}
```

Comment: In your case, `TestSynchronizationContext.Post` does get called by `YieldAwaitable` logic, but [all it does by default](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/synchronizationcontext.cs,16705ba05372139e,references) is calling `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` for the continuation callback. So after the `await` you end up on a random `ThreadPool` thread without any synchronization context at all, and without your `Culture` object.

Comment: Change your test case: instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew(...).Wait();`, place `var task=Task.Factory.StartNew(...); Thread.Sleep(1000); task.Wait();`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `SychronizationContext` must set itself as `Current`. If your `SynchronizationContext` is for a dedicated thread, you can just set current once in your main loop; if it uses thread pool threads to execute (as in your example code), you should set it whenever you borrow one of the threads (and clear it before returning the thread to the thread pool, of course).

Comment: But for example, if I start a new Task, inside that Task, it will have the correct Context. It's only after a Task.Yield.

Comment: @MindingData: I'm not sure what you mean by "start a new `Task`". If you mean "call an `async Task` method", then yes, `Current` is still the same, since you're on the same thread. OTOH, if you *actually* "start a new `Task`" (i.e., use `Task.Run`), then `Current` will not be transferred to the new task.

Comment: Added an edit for you. When starting a task, it can accept a TaskScheduler param of which I can pass in the Sync Context so I am able to get it working in that sense, but unable to use it this way using Task.Yield()

Comment: @MindingData: My answer is still the same: If you have a custom `SynchronizationContext`, you must take care of setting it as current. Your test is running into a race condition where [it decides to execute the task *on the thread that's waiting for it*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/10/15/9907713.aspx). To see your test take the other path of that race condition, capture the `StartNew` task, do a `Sleep`, and *then* `Wait`; or *clear* the calling thread's SyncCtx before calling `StartNew(..).Wait()`.